# SQL Modeling - hint + best practice

Tags: sql, database, modeling

I'm starting a little project asp.net 4.5 + SQL 2008R2 for my friend so he can stop managing is outfitters on paper ;-)

He can rent multiple chalet and he can rent other products (motors, kayak, little boat, fishing line, ...)

I started by creating a table for the chalet named ***chalets*** and a table for the product that can be rented named ***products***. But now I'm questionning myself if I should just have 1 single table and have both in it ? Both are gonna have a price history change but ***chalets*** is gonna have multiple field that are not used by the ***products*** (example : #of room, # of bed, max person, water ?, electicity ? ...). Products is basically just name and description.

What's the best pratice here ? At what point we merge or split stuff like in my example ?

Thanks for the help

Richard

Comment: You're probably going to take a beating here.  This is really a general opinion question.  SO is around specific problems/questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends and performance wise, nothing is going to decide it but testing and benchmarking.

Best practice is to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data.

In your case you have to ask yourself: "Is a chalet another product to rent?"  Or do certain products belong to certain chalets.

If you agree with the first, it would make more sense to merge the definitions, if you are looking more towards the altter it would probably be better to split the tables.

Either way, with small sets of data (as it sounds you are handling [<1M rows]) performance wise it won't matter to much and you could choose whatever makes most sense to you.

Comment: Well, the number of data in product and chalet wont be more than 20 row for both ;-) and there's no real life relation with the chalet and the product. Poeple could only go fishing and rent product without staying in a chalet ;-). I think that I'm gonna split them ;-). Thanks for the hint and the link.

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it is have your 'products' table with a 'product type' column and an extension table 'chalets' that would be tied to the products table (the Chalet type) with a primary-foreign key relationship.

This model allows you to add other tables if other types of 'products' require other data to be tracked as well.